# Javascript table not working correctly

Tags: javascript, css-tables

[image]

I'm trying to figure out why that table is showing like that, I mean, how to set every col to ocuppy the full width of the table frame?

Here's the function that creates the table:

```
function rp_insertTable() {

    FM_log(3,"rp_insertTable() called");

    var farmTable = dom.cn("table");

    var ftableBody = dom.cn("tbody");

    var i;

    var maximize = GM_getValue("Maximize_" + suffixGlobal, 0);

    farmTable.className = "FMtbg";

    farmTable.id = "farmMachineTable";

    farmTable.setAttribute('cellpadding', 2);

    farmTable.setAttribute('cellspacing', 1);

    farmTable.style.marginBotton = "12px";

    farmTable.width = 1000;

    //farmTable.innerHTML = "<font size=1>";

    //farmTable.style.fontSize = "8px";

    //top row

    var tableRow = dom.cn("tr");

    tableRow.className = "cbg1";

    tableRow.width = "100%";

    var tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    tableCol.style.width = 1000;

//  tableCol.setAttribute("colspan", 15);

    var Button = dom.cn("div");

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

    //Add Minimize||Maximize button

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    var img = dom.cn("img");

    if (maximize) {

        img.src = image['MINIMIZE']; //add minimize image

        img.title = T("Minimize");

    } else {

        img.src = image['MAXIMIZE']; //add minimize image

        img.title = T("Maximize");

    }

    img.style.height = '16px';

    img.style.width = '30px';

    img.style.cursor = "pointer";

    Button = dom.cn("div");

    Button.setAttribute("style", "width:30px;float:right;");

    Button.appendChild(img);

    Button.addEventListener('click', function() {

                rp_min_max();

            }, 0);

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);



    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

    ftableBody.appendChild(tableRow); //adding the top row



    //********************************

    // option row

    tableRow = dom.cn("tr");

    tableRow.className = "cbg1";

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    //tableCol.setAttribute("colspan", 15);



    if(GM_getValue("MaximizeSettings_" + suffixGlobal, 0)==1) {

    tableRow = dom.cn("tr");

    tableRow.className = "cbg1";

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    //tableCol.setAttribute("colspan", 15);



    var settingsTable = dom.cn('table');

    settingsTable.width = "100%";

    settingsTable.setAttribute("margin-bottom",10);



    //1st option: randomiz farming

    var setRowRandomize = dom.cn('tr');



    var setRandomizeC1 = dom.cn('td');

    setRandomizeC1.width = 20;



    RandomButton = createInputButton("checkbox", 0, setRandomFarming);

    var random = GM_getValue("RandomFarming_" + suffixGlobal, 0);

    if (random == 1) {

        RandomButton.checked = true;

    }



    setRandomizeC1.appendChild(RandomButton);



    var setRandomizeC2 = dom.cn('td');

    setRandomizeC2.innerHTML = T('SETRANDOMIZE');



    setRowRandomize.appendChild(setRandomizeC1);

    setRowRandomize.appendChild(setRandomizeC2);



    //2nd option: delete temporary list

    var setRowDelTList = dom.cn('tr');



    var setTListC1 = dom.cn('td');

    setTListC1.width = 20;



    TListButton = createInputButton("checkbox", 0, setDelTList);

    var TList = GM_getValue("DelTList_" + suffixGlobal, 0);

    if (TList == 1) {

        TListButton.checked = true;

    }



    setTListC1.appendChild(TListButton);



    var setTListC2 = dom.cn('td');

    setTListC2.innerHTML = T('SETDELTLIST');



    setRowDelTList.appendChild(setTListC1);

    setRowDelTList.appendChild(setTListC2);



    //3rd option: read reports to make a priority queue

    var setRowReadRep = dom.cn('tr');



    var setReadRepC1 = dom.cn('td');

    setReadRepC1.width = 20;



    ReadRepButton = createInputButton("checkbox", 0, setReadRep);

    var ReadRep = GM_getValue("ReadRep_" + suffixGlobal, 0);

    if (ReadRep == 1) {

        ReadRepButton.checked = true;

    }



    setReadRepC1.appendChild(ReadRepButton);



    var setReadRepC2 = dom.cn('td');

    setReadRepC2.innerHTML = T('SETREADREP');



    setRowReadRep.appendChild(setReadRepC1);

    setRowReadRep.appendChild(setReadRepC2);



    //4th option: skipping of Villages

    var setRowVilSkip = dom.cn('tr');



    var setVilSkipC1 = dom.cn('td');

    setVilSkipC1.width = 20;



    SkipButton = createInputButton("checkbox", 0, setVillageSkipping);

    var vilSkip = GM_getValue("VillageSkipping_" + suffixGlobal, 0);

    if (vilSkip == 1) {

        SkipButton.checked = true;

    }



    setVilSkipC1.appendChild(SkipButton);



    var setVilSkipC2 = dom.cn('td');

    setVilSkipC2.innerHTML = T('SETVILSKIP');



    setRowVilSkip.appendChild(setVilSkipC1);

    setRowVilSkip.appendChild(setVilSkipC2);





    //5th option: marking of Farms

    var setRowFarmMark = dom.cn('tr');



    var setFarmMarkC1 = dom.cn('td');

    setFarmMarkC1.width = 20;



    farmMarkButton = createInputButton("checkbox", 0, setFarmMarking);

    var farmMark = GM_getValue("farmMarking_" + suffixGlobal, 0);

    if (farmMark == 1) {

        farmMarkButton.checked = true;

    }



    setFarmMarkC1.appendChild(farmMarkButton);



    var setFarmMarkC2 = dom.cn('td');

    setFarmMarkC2.innerHTML = T('FARMMARKING');



    setRowFarmMark.appendChild(setFarmMarkC1);

    setRowFarmMark.appendChild(setFarmMarkC2);





    // adding settingRows to the table

    settingsTable.appendChild(setRowRandomize);

    settingsTable.appendChild(setRowDelTList);

    settingsTable.appendChild(setRowReadRep);

    settingsTable.appendChild(setRowVilSkip);

    settingsTable.appendChild(setRowFarmMark);



    // add table

    tableCol.appendChild(settingsTable);





    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

        ftableBody.appendChild(tableRow); //add to table    

    }



    //********************************

    // end option row



    //second row

    tableRow = dom.cn("tr");

    tableRow.className = "cbg1";

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

//  tableCol.setAttribute("colspan", 24);

    tableCol.width = "100%";

    tableCol.appendChild(createInputButton("submit", T('START_FARMING'),

            startEngine));

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

    ftableBody.appendChild(tableRow); //adding the second row


    //third row

    tableRow = dom.cn("tr");

    tableRow.className = "cbg1";

//------------------------------------------------------------------

    //checkbox

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    //tableCol.width = "80%";

    tableCol.style.fontSize = "13px";

    //tableCol.style.fontWeigth = "bold";

    //tableCol.style.fontFamily = "Arial";

    tableCol.appendChild(createLinkButton("X", T('CHECKFARM_M'), function() {rp_marcadesmarcaFarm(true)}));

    tableCol.appendChild(createLinkButton("0", T('CHECKFARM_M'), function() {rp_marcadesmarcaFarm(false)}));

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);
//------------------------------------------------------------------

    //start

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    tableCol.innerHTML = "<div style='cursor:help;' class='b' title='"

            + T('START_M') + "'>S</div>";

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

//------------------------------------------------------------------

    //end

  if (opcaoEND) {   

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    //tableCol.innerHTML = "<div style='cursor:pointer;' class='b' title='Select End Position'>E</div>";

    //tableCol.addEventListener("click",rp_removeEndIndex,false);

    tableCol.appendChild(createLinkButton("E", T('END_M'), rp_removeEndIndex));

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);
  }

//------------------------------------------------------------------

    //edit

  if (opcaoEDIT) {  

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    tableCol.innerHTML = "<div style='cursor:help;' class='b' title='"

            + T('EDIT_M') + "'>E</div>";

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);
  }

//------------------------------------------------------------------

    //delete

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    tableCol.innerHTML = "<div style='cursor:help;' class='b' title='"

            + T('DELETE_M') + "'>D</div>";

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

//------------------------------------------------------------------

    //farm

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    tableCol.appendChild(createLinkButton(T('FARM') + " &#8595;",

            T('SORT_FARM'), sortFarms));

    tableCol.width = "100%";

//  tableCol.setAttribute("colspan", 8);

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

//------------------------------------------------------------------

    //imagens

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    tableCol.innerHTML = '<td><img src="img/x.gif" class="unit u' + user_race + '"></td>';

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        tableCol = dom.cn("td");

        tableCol.innerHTML = '<td><img src="img/x.gif" class="unit u' + (user_race + i)

                + '"></td>';

        tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------

    //hero

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    tableCol.width = "1";

    tableCol.innerHTML = '<td><img src="img/x.gif" class="unit uhero" width="1px"></td>';

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

    ftableBody.appendChild(tableRow); //adding the 3rd row

    //add List



    //getting first farm in list for sIndex

    prioque = GM_getValue('priorityqueue'+ suffixLocal, '').split('>:)');

    fque = GM_getValue('farmqueue'+ suffixLocal, '').split('>:)');



    if (prioque.length >= 1 && prioque[0].length > 2)

    {

        var arr = prioque[0].split("|");

        var tX = arr[0].split(",")[0];

        var tY = arr[0].split(",")[1];

        var sIndex = getSindexFromXY(tX,tY, suffixLocal);

    } else if (fque.length >= 1 && fque[0].length > 2){

        var arr = fque[0].split("|");

        var tX = arr[0].split(",")[0];

        var tY = arr[0].split(",")[1];

        var sIndex = getSindexFromXY(tX,tY, suffixLocal);

    } else {

        sIndex = getStartIndex();

    }



    FM_log(4,"starting farmrows for: "+suffixLocal);

    farmList = GM_getValue("FarmList_" + suffixLocal, "");

    totalTroops = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (farmList != "" && farmList != null) {

        farmList = farmList.split(">:)");

        var eIndex = getEndIndex();

        FM_log(3,"sIndex="+sIndex+"/eIndex="+eIndex);


        if (farmList.length > 0) {

            for (i = 0; i < farmList.length; i++) {

                if (maximize == 1) {

                    tableRow = rp_createFarmRow(i, sIndex, eIndex);

                    if (tableRow != null) {

                        ftableBody.appendChild(tableRow);

                    }

                } else { //the i have to count totalTroops here

                    var arr = farmList[i].split("|");

                    if (arr[7] == 'true') {

                        arr[1] = arr[1].split(",");

                        for (var j = 0; j < arr[1].length; j++) {

                            totalTroops[j] += parseInt(arr[1][j]);

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    } else {

        tableCol = dom.cn("td");

    //  tableCol.setAttribute("colspan", 18);

        tableCol.innerHTML = "<div style='margin: auto;'>" + T('NO_FARM_YET')

                + "</div>";

        tableCol.style.fontSize = "13px";

        tableCol.style.fontWeigth = "bold";

        tableCol.style.fontFamily = "Arial";

        ftableBody.appendChild(tableCol);

    }

    //bottom row

    tableRow = dom.cn("tr");

    tableRow.className = "cbg1";

    tableCol = dom.cn("td");

//  tableCol.setAttribute("colspan", 7);

    //add space

    //Button = dom.cn("div");

    //Button.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

    //Button.setAttribute("style", "width:10px;float:left;");

    //tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    //Optimize button

    img = dom.cn("img");

    img.src = image['OPTIMIZE'];

    img.title = T('OPTIMIZE_M');

    img.style.height = '16px';

    img.style.width = '16px';

    img.style.cursor = "pointer";

    Button = dom.cn("div");

    Button.setAttribute("style", "width:16px;float:left;");

    Button.appendChild(img);

    Button.addEventListener('click', function() {

                optimizeFarmsByDistance();

            }, 0);

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    //add space

    Button = dom.cn("div");

    Button.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

    Button.setAttribute("style", "width:5px;float:left;");

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    //Import/Export Button

    img = dom.cn("img");

    img.src = image['IM_EXPORT'];

    img.title = T('LOCAL_IM_EX_M');

    img.style.height = '16px';

    img.style.width = '16px';

    img.style.cursor = "pointer";

    Button = dom.cn("div");

    Button.setAttribute("style", "width:16px;float:left;");

    Button.appendChild(img);

    Button.addEventListener('click', function() {

                importExport();

            }, 0);

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    //add space

    Button = dom.cn("div");

    Button.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

    Button.setAttribute("style", "width:5px;float:left;");

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    //globalImportExport

    img = dom.cn("img");

    img.src = image['GIM_EXPORT'];

    img.title = T('GLOBAL_IM_EX_M');

    img.style.height = '16px';

    img.style.width = '16px';

    img.style.cursor = "pointer";

    Button = dom.cn("div");

    Button.setAttribute("style", "width:16px;float:left;");

    Button.appendChild(img);

    Button.addEventListener('click', function() {

                globalImportExport();

            }, 0);

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    //add space

    Button = dom.cn("div");

    Button.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

    Button.setAttribute("style", "width:5px;float:left;");

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    //Delete Farm list Button   

    img = dom.cn("img");

    img.src = image['DELTEMPLIST'];

    img.title = T('DELTEMPLIST');

    img.style.height = '16px';

    img.style.width = '16px';

    img.style.cursor = "pointer";

    Button = dom.cn("div");

    Button.setAttribute("style", "width:16px;float:left;");

    Button.appendChild(img);

    Button.addEventListener('click', function() {

                clearque();

                alert("Farmlist and Prioritylist deleted");

            }, 0);

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    //add space

    Button = dom.cn("div");

    Button.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

    Button.setAttribute("style", "width:5px;float:left;");

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);

    //Settings Button

    img = dom.cn("img");

    img.src = image['SETTINGS'];

    img.title = T('UPDATE_SETTINGS');

    img.style.height = '16px';

    img.style.width = '16px';

    img.style.cursor = "pointer";

    Button = dom.cn("div");

    Button.setAttribute("style", "width:16px;float:left;");

    Button.appendChild(img);

    Button.addEventListener('click', function() {

                min_max_settings();

            }, 0);

    tableCol.appendChild(Button);



    //append the row in the table

    tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);


    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

        tableCol = dom.cn("td");

        tableCol.innerHTML = totalTroops[i];

        tableRow.appendChild(tableCol);

    }

    ftableBody.appendChild(tableRow);

    farmTable.appendChild(ftableBody);



    var container = dom.get("content");

    container.appendChild(farmTable);   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what your JavaScript code is doing... but I wanted to make a suggestion. you might find it easier to not set any absolute widths or CSS in your JavaScript code and instead add a CSS class name using JavaScript, and then, in CSS do something like:

```
table.farmTable {
  width: 100%;
}

table.farmTable tr td.checkmarks,
table.farmTable tr td.radiobuttons {
  width: 50px;
}

table.farmTable tr td.farmNames {
  width: 20%;
}

/* and more styles here... */
```

I'm not sure if that helps at all or if I'm just making pointless noise ;-)

Comment: the problem is that farmTable.width is not working. As you can see in the table image I posted, the first row´s of the table are getting half the width size, and I don´t know why is that. If you can help me with that, it would be very welcome.

Comment: What if you specify the width using CSS, does it work then? It's very difficult for me to help without being able to use FireBug to manipulate the actual HTMl of the page... maybe someone smarter than I can be of more help!

Comment: none of the .width is working... and .style.width not working also. I´m getting crazy with this fuc*** table, you change something and nothing happens, I think the problem is some sort of over value, like when you set one col to 90% and the other one to 60%, so the value doesn´t work. perhaps that´s why I change .width and nothing happens, but I really need help with this thing.

Comment: @Fernando: Uggggghhh!!! I feel your pain, I really do. Been there, done that. I hate it so much. :-) Is there any way you can post a link to a page I can play with using firebug?

Comment: no, cause you would need to create a travian account, install greasemonkey then install farming machine to be able to test it =/ what dom.cn stands for?

Comment: If nobody else answers I'll see what I can do tomorrow... Headed out for the night.